# Is there literature on use of Conditional Odds Ratios to estimate Marginal Odds Ratios? Is COR equal to 1 when MOR is?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, marginal-effect

I write my questions in brief here upon requests from IWS (thanks for your reply):

1) Has anyone ever given a proof that Marginal Odds Ratio$=1->$ Conditional Odds Ratio$=1$ (let's call them $MOR$ and $COR)$? Because, in this case, we could consider the test on $COR=1$ and $MOR=1$ equivalent.

2) Has anyone ever studied the bias of using $COR$s to estimate $MOR$s?

Below the long-version question:

It seems to me it is recognized that both Conditional Odds Ratios ($COR$s) and Marginal Odds Ratios ($MOR$s) may be quantities of interest, but measuring different things: the $COR$ an individual effect, while the $MOR$ a population-based effect (see, for example, Burgess, 2013). However, while I found literature discussing the bias of using $MOR$ to estimate $COR$, I didn't find anything about doing the opposite: using $COR$s to estimate $MOR$s.

1) Is it due to the fact that $MOR$ is a confusing term, given in literature not related to treatment effects/the counterfactual setting it's used with the meaning of "crude $OR$"? Or because it's easier to estimate $MOR$s than $COR$s, so the problem of estimating $MOR$s by using $COR$s never occurs?

2) I read, in a paper (Gail et al., 1984), after referring to a Corollary showing that, when $COR$ is $1$, then also $MOR$ (or better saying any $OR$ estimated by omitting covariates) is $1$:

> This is in accord with the very general validity of significance tests
>   of the null hypothesis $\alpha = 0$ which are based on the
>   randomization distribution. Such tests, of course, have valid size,
>   regardless of what covariates may or may not have been omitted, and
>   regardless of the form of the population model.

So, authors state that a test having, as null hypothesis, $Log(COR)=0$ may be valid even if performed on $Log(MOR)$. Also, again in Burgess (2013), it is stated:

> Although odds ratios typically differ depending on covariate
>   adjustment, a null causal association of X on Y leads to an odds ratio
>   of one no matter which covariates the odds ratio is considered to be
>   marginal and conditional across.

Is there a mathematical demonstration that the sentences in these papers are correct? What I'm interested about, in particular, is that also $MOR=1 -> COR=1$ holds, so that we could conclude that $COR=1 <=> MOR=1$. I also found another paper about the estimation of the non-collapsbility effect (Pang et al., 2013), but they repeat conditions for collapsibility of $OR$s are at least one among: $COR$=1; no effect of the covariate on the outcome; independence between treatment and the covariate *conditional on the outcome*. I would find the demonstration I'm looking for is trivial ($MOR=1->MRR=1->CRR=1->COR=1$, being RR the relative risk/risk ratio), exploiting the fact a $OR$ of $1$ corresponds to a $RR$ of $1$, and *viceversa*. However, Samuels (1981) warns about the fact that the risk ratio is only collapsible if it constant. Is constancy of $OR$s (thus, $RR$s) an obvious assumption (otherwise, an interaction term would be added) or not?

**Edit 03 July**

I've realized that there is a problem: we should add the condition that $COR$ is constant across individuals. Moreover, the demonstration I'm giving above ($MOR=1->MRR=1->CRR=1->COR=1$) is invalid, because it would require, as additional hypothesis, not a constant $COR$, but a constant $CRR$.

Bibliography

Burgess S, CRP CHD Genetics Collaboration. **Identifying the odds ratio estimated by a two-stage instrumental variable analysis with a logistic regression model**. *Statistics in medicine*. 2013; 32(27), 4726-4747.

Gail M, Wieand S, Piantadosi S. **Biased estimates of treatment effect in randomized experiments with nonlinear regressions and omitted covariates**. *Biometrika*. 1984; 71(3), 431–444.

Pang, M., Kaufman, J.S., Platt, R.W. **Studying noncollapsibility of the odds ratio with marginal structural and logistic regression models**. *Stat Methods Med Res*. 2013; 0(0), 1-13

Samuels, M. **Matching and Design Efficiency in Epidemiological Studies**. *Biometrika*. 1981; 68(3), 577-588.

Comment: I have a feeling this question might be very interesting, but it is a long read with multiple questions 'hidden' among the sentences. Could you reformat the text a little to show what your main concern(s) is/are? (maybe state the questions clearly at the top or bottom)

Comment: Thank you IWS. I have added a few lines on top to synthetize my questions.